# Django + AJAX - POST 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to implement a like functionality in my Django app using AJAX but, when I try to do that I'm getting an `POST http://localhost:8000/forum/like/ 404 (Not Found)`. All I wanna do is to add/remove users from the likes list without refreshing the entire page.

### views.py

```
@require_POST 
def toggle_like(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug)

        if question.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            question.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            question.likes.add(user)
    
    context = {'likes-count': question.likes.count}

    return HttpResponse(json.dump(context), content_type='application/json')
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'forum'

urlpatterns = [
    path('like/', views.toggle_like, name='toggle-like'),
]
```

### question.html

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        $('#like').click(() => {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "{% url 'forum:toggle-like' %}",
                data: {
                    'slug': $(this).attr('name'),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: (response) => {
                    alert(response.message);
                },
                error: (response, error) => {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock  %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Likes: {{ question.likes.count }} <input type="button" id="like" name="{{ question.slug }}" value="Like" /></p>
{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: [Please read the explanation of the error code 404](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Statuscode). If this does not answer your question, please debug your url variable to validate that it contains the url you are expecting.

Comment: I'm a hundred percent sure that is everything ok with my url.

Comment: Can you call the __exact__ url in your browser?

Comment: Yeah, it gives me a blank page and nothinhg is showed in the browser console. But looking for some errors in the django console I found the following message: 'Method Not Allowed (GET): /forum/like/
[10/Jan/2018 11:41:50] "GET /forum/like/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0'